# Generic and extension of component prop type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-functional-component

We have two React components (the 2nd one uses the 1st one in both props and rendering).

`ReadOnlyField` is defined as follow:

```
type ReadOnlyFieldProps<T> = {
  value: T;
  format: (value: T) => string;
  // ...rest
}

const ReadOnlyField = <T extends any>(props: ReadOnlyFieldProps<T>) => {
  return (); // render something
}
```

Now the `EditableField` uses the `ReadOnlyField` component:

```
type EditableFieldProps<T> = ReadOnlyFieldProps<T> & {
  onChange: (newValue: T) => void;
}

const EditableField = <T extends any>({ onChange, ...props}: EditableFieldProps<T>) => {
  return (<>
    <ReadOnlyField {...props} />
    {/* some other stuff */}
  </>);
}
```

Strangely typescript cannot infer generic type T of ReadOnlyProp based on provided value type inside `EditableField`. I receive the following error:

> Type '{ value: T; format: ((value: T) => string); ... }' is not assignable to type 'ReadonlyFieldProps<unknown>'

Expo snack for TS error reproduction: https://snack.expo.dev/@signa89/react-native-ts-test (check `EF.tsx`).

How can I define the type of `EditableFieldProps` in a way

1. to extend the type of `ReadOnlyFieldProps`
2. and prevent the generic type of `ReadOnlyField` from being inferred as `unknown`
   ?

**Note:** I also tried using `interface`s with no luck.

Comment: I don't get any error [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKBgE8wlFUATAeQDsAbGgMWCQ6YAFHGADOAHgAqAPjgBeOAG8qcOADcUHAK5IAXHEkVKqzNBAoY+gBQbtegwEp5s0TCjA2AcyOqA9L7gAOmCiVyoAXyMqNAg2V0YUVk4ePgF5OCk4JAAPGCQ2JlE4FDYaaSswEVF9ZET2Ll5+ISqpaSc5WWVjOCIYLSg2ODYtDg4jSKpJ6joGAFEmYBgUACMOJEaBYQgxVvTapIbU5u2JGTgAMiUVOFiAYQALEs97KzYkAHcANU0dfUl22RqCDAJjjKYxOLweaLFZrDZMdKZHJ5ApFEplKyKG5sB5PJAAGiCwUqJzg4X00KWq3WRy2OxkAKu3V6-UGVnE0muqnE+3qKSaSmCgRJYnCcF8nO6qkUvgAVHBRLgGBAYPckFAFX1MJg4LLfOFruIJQ5xkA)

Comment: Thank you for checking. I also checked the project you sent and it seems to be error-free. I am using react-native with its default ts configuration (@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json). Can that be the source of the problem? any ideas?

Comment: can you share the tsconfig that you are using?

Comment: This is the content: `{ "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json" }`. And here is the link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tsconfig/react-native (the contents of the json file is available in the link).

Comment: Still can't reproduce. Can you maybe create a sandbox or any other minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Here it is: https://snack.expo.dev/4fmAbp7po (In the components folder, check EF.tsx).

Comment: It seems that snacks show no error. Ideally I would be able to see the error in your example

Comment: The code is not used. I just copied my own code. If you check EF.tsx file, you can see that there is a red line on `<ReadOnlyField ...`.

Comment: Try `<ReadonlyField<T> // props />`

Comment: As soon as I removed `React.memo` for the export, both versions (`<ReadOnlyField` and `<ReadOnlyField<T>`) are working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was in exporting the parent component (`ReadOnlyField`) as a memo (i.e. `export default React.memo(ReadOnlyField)`). When I removed the `memo` function and exported it regularly (`export default ReadOnlyField`), the error is gone.